# How to display an alert only while a function loads? | Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Essentially I have the following JSON script that fetches data. I would like to display the following loading alert animation only while the FetchJSON is loading the data.

How can this loading alert be presented only for the remainder of the time it takes for FetchJSON to load.

**Loading Alert Code:**

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50))
    loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    loadingIndicator.style = UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.gray
    loadingIndicator.startAnimating();

    alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 8.0) {
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

    }
```

**FetchJSON Code:**

```
private func fetchJSON() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/example/example"),
        let value = driverName.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)
        else { return }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = "Name=\(value)".data(using: .utf8)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
        guard let data = data else { return }


        do {
            self.structure = try JSONDecoder().decode([ScheduleStructure].self,from:data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }

        }.resume()

}
```

Comment: That's not what `UIAlertController` is for.

Comment: So it cannot be displayed for the duration of the function loading data?

Comment: @ElTomato How could just a loading animation be displayed for the duration of fetchJSON loading?

Comment: You can add a `UIView` to the view hierarchy, then add a `UIActivityIndicator` as the subview of that view. Then manually set `isHidden`.

Comment: Yes but what identifies that the indicator should hide?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to declare an instance variable to hold a reference to the `UIAlertController`:

```
private var alert: UIAlertController?
func displayAlert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50))
    loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    loadingIndicator.style = UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.gray
    loadingIndicator.startAnimating();

    alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    self.alert = alert
}

private func fetchJSON() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/example/example"),
        let value = driverName.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)
        else { return }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = "Name=\(value)".data(using: .utf8)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            self.structure = try JSONDecoder().decode([ScheduleStructure].self,from:data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.alert?.dismiss(animated: true) { self.alert?.view.removeFromSuperview() }
            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: The loading alert is not appearing when the fetchJSON is being loaded

Comment: Where do you call `displayAlert` (or whatever you name it in your program)? It should not be called during `viewDidLoad`. The earliest you should call it is in `viewDidAppear`